# Old-style classes, new-style classes and metaclasses

Tags: python, class, metaclass, new-style-class

In Python 2.x, all new-style classes inherit from `object` implicitly or explicitly. Then look at this:

```
>>> class M(type):
...     pass
...
>>> class A:
...     __metaclass__ = M
...
>>> class B:
...     pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
```

```
>>> type(A)
<class '__main__.M'>
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Does this mean `A` is a new-style class? But `A` doesn't inherit from `object` anyway, right?

```
>>> type(B)
<class 'classobj'>
>>> type(b)
<type 'instance'>
```

OK, `B` is a classic class, isn't it?

```
>>> isinstance(A, object)
True
>>> isinstance(B, object)
True
```

why are instances of both `A` and `B` instances of `object`?

If `B` is an instance of `object`, then `type(B)` wouldn't be `classobj`, right?

Comment: You shouldn't have put the `__slots__` thing in this question. It's another question entirely.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, yes, I just realized that.

Comment: A is a new style class, since *'new-style classes are constructed using type()'* and you have set it's metaclass to `type`. Old-style classes use `types.ClassType`

Comment: @jamylak, as you can see, `A` doesn't inherit from `object`, but I still use `__metaclass__` in `A`, is this OK? Cuz I thougt, `__metaclass__` can only be used with class inheriting from `object`, right?

Comment: `__metaclass__` is used in every class. Every class has a metaclass which constructs it.

Answer (score 5):

About metaclasses you may read here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation. Generally metaclasses are intended to work with new style classes. When you write:

```
class M(type):
    pass
```

and you use:

```
class C:
    __metaclass__ = M
```

you will create a new style object because the way M is defined (default implementation uses `type` to create a new-style class). You could always implement you own metaclass that would create old-style classes using `types.ClassType`.

Answer (score 1):

About slots you may read here http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/slots.html, a fragment:

> By default, instances of both old and new-style classes have a dictionary for attribute storage.

For new-style classes you may add `__slots__`, then the per-object dictionary will not be created.